# How stable is C/C++ structure padding under the AAPCS (ARM ABI)?

Tags: c++, c, arm, padding, abi

## Question

The [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) tells us:

> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

and

> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

I am assuming this applies to any of the C++ standards too, but I have not checked them.

Let's assume a C/C++ application (i.e. both languages are used in the application) running on an ARM Cortex-M would store some persistent data on a local medium (a serial NOR-flash chip for instance), and read it back after power cycling, possibly after an upgrade of the application itself in the future. The upgraded application may have been compiled with an upgraded compiler (we assume gcc).

Let's further assume that the developer is lazy (that's not me, of course), and directly streams some plain C or C++ `struct`s to flash, instead of first serializing them as any <s>paranoid</s> experienced developer would do.

In fact, the developer in question is lazy, but not totally ignorant, since he has read the [AAPCS (Procedure Call Standard for the Arm Architecture)](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0042/i/aapcs32.pdf).

His rationale, besides laziness, is the following:

- He does not want to pack the `struct`s to avoid misalignment problems in the rest of the application.
- The AAPCS specifies a fixed alignment for every single fundamental data type.
- The only rational motivation for padding is to achieve proper alignment.
- Therefore, he thinks, padding (and therefore member `offsetof` and total `sizeof`) is fully determined for any C or C++ `struct` by the AAPCS.
- Therefore, he further reasons, there is no way my application would not be able to interpret some read back data that an earlier version of the same application would have written (assuming, of course, that the offset of the data in flash memory has not changed between writing and reading).

However, the developer has a conscience and he is a little worried:

- The C standard does not mention any reason for padding. Achieving proper alignment may be the only rational reason for padding, but compilers are free to pad as much as they want, according to the standard.
- How can he be sure that his compiler really follows the [AAPCS](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0042/i/aapcs32.pdf)?
- Could his assumptions suddenly be broken by some apparently unrelated compiler flag that he would start using, or by a compiler upgrade?

My question is: how dangerously does that lazy developer live? In other words, how stable is padding in C/C++ `struct`s under the assumptions above?

## Conclusion

Two weeks after this question was asked, the only answer that has been
received does not really answer the asked question. I have also asked
the exact same question [on an ARM community forum](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-m-forum/46880/how-stable-is-c-c-structure-padding-under-the-aapcs-arm-abi),
but got no answer at all.

I however choose to accept [3246135](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397572/3246135) as the answer because:

1. I take the absence of proper answer as very relevant information
   for this case. The correctness of solutions to software problems
   should be obvious. The assumptions made in my question may be true,
   but I cannot easily prove it. Additionally, if the assumptions are
   incorrect, the consequences, in the general case, could be
   catastrophic.
2. Compared to the risk, the burden on the developer when using the
   strategy exposed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397572/3246135) seems
   very reasonable. Assuming a constant endianness (which is quite easy
   to enforce), it is a hundred percent-safe (any deviation will generate
   an error at compile-time) and it is much lighter than a full-blown
   serialization. Basically, the strategy exposed in
   [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397572/3246135) is a mandatory minimum
   price to pay in order to make one's C/C++ `struct`s persistent independently of any ABI.

If you are a developer asking yourself the question above, **please do
not be lazy**, and use instead the strategy exposed in the accepted
answer, or an alternative strategy that **guarantees a constant padding
across software releases**.

Comment: An alternative that you may not have considered: define two versions of the struct, one that's packed, the other not. Before storing the struct, copy all members from the non-packed struct to the packed struct. Then write to non-volatile memory. To restore from non-volatile memory, read into the packed struct, then copy the members to the non-packed struct for use by the application. Be sure to only use types from `<stdint.h>` (at least in the packed struct) so that the compiler cannot go and change the sizes on you.

Comment: @user3386109, thanks. The developer has used that method plenty (before getting lazy).

Comment: This padding can change with compiler options.  Some CPU have more strict alignment due to the bus architecture.  For instance, a 16 bit bus can not guarantee atomic 32bit load without some extra bus locking infrastructure.  Even an unaligned 16bit transfer will not be atomic.  You can extend this to other types, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128.  So the CPU itself can result in additional padding.  For instance, storing function pointers could be problematic as they may/may not have the low bit set.  Also, what guarantee do you have the the toolsuite is 100% AAPCS compliant (to some arbitrary version)?

Comment: Some glaring omission in PRO/CONS are the overhead of serialization/deserialization code;  Both run-time and memory.  No code tends to have zero bugs.  As well, some serialization code can actually result in reduced NV-memory foot print (most 32bit values are actually in the range 0-255).  If you choose packing, I would have some sort of run-time verification of assumptions that runs at start-up.  If you have CI/CD, then a test suite may be sufficient.  Static analysis tools may also be able to verify that assumptions are valid.  Ie, no function pointers in these structs.

Comment: The C/C++ standards are irrelevant here, since as you note they don't address the issue of where padding is or isn't.  All you care about is what the ABI says, and whether your compiler complies with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can never by 100% sure that the compiler won't introduce padding in some capacity.  However, you can mitigate the risks by following a few rules:

- Use fixed size types for all members, i.e. `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, etc.
- Start each member at an offset that is a multiple of the member's size (or if the member is an array / struct, the size of the largest member).
- Avoid bitfields

Note that doing this will likely introduce some explicit padding fields to satisfy alignment.

For example:

```
struct orig {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c[10];
    short d;
    char e[15];
    long f;
    int g;
};
```

The size of this struct's members, assuming `sizeof(short) == 2`, `sizeof(int) == 4`, and `sizeof(long) == 8`, would be 74.  If you take into account likely padding:

```
struct orig_padded {
    int a;
    char b;
    char pad1[3];
    int c[10];
    short d;
    char e[15];
    char pad2[7];
    long f;
    int g;
    char pad3[4];
};
```

You have a struct size of 88.

With some rearranging we can reduce the size back to 74:

```
struct reordered {
    int64_t f;
    int32_t a;
    int32_t c[10];
    int32_t g;
    int16_t d;
    char b;
    char e[15];
};
```

By ordering the fields in descending order of size, we basically remove padding between the fields and only leave potential padding at the end.  Note also the use of fixed sizes to avoid some surprises.  Then as a safeguard, we add:

```
static_assert(sizeof(struct reordered) == 74);
```

So if the compiled size of the struct ever changes, you'll know at compile time.

For more details, take a look at [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing).

Comment: While these advices are generally speaking very wise, I would really like to read some ARM ABI specifics.

Comment: Also, please note that while avoiding any padding is one way to ensure constant padding, my goal here is really constant padding, not absence of padding.

Comment: My understanding is that the `int64_t` should be the first field, i.e. fields ordered from largest to smallest.  This may affect padding before the struct (such as aligning to a 64-bit boundary), but not affect the padding within the structure.

Comment: That is an excellent link on structure packing.  The best part for the OP is the `static_assert` which may verify things at build time to make sure that tools are invariant to any assumptions.  Not having any pointers in the data makes packed structures in-lieu of serialization easier.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You don't necessarily have to have the largest elements first if you ensure that what comes before lines up properly, but yes you're less likely to have padding (and less likely to make a mistake) if the largest fields come first.  I've updated the example to use this ordering.